# Can I pass a UDS file descriptor through another UDS connection in c or c++

Tags: c++, c, linux, network-programming

I am trying to pass an established connection Unix Domain Socket file descriptor from process A to process B through another Unix Domain Socket connection, with no luck
although a tcp socket is passed with no problem.
Is there a reason to it or am I doing something wrong?
Both are passed through ancilary message
Thanx

Comment: please post some code showing your observed problem.

Comment: I am trying to understand if there is a known limitation for passing fd that represent an opened UDS connection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Socket file descriptor (just like a regular file descriptors) have absolutely no meaning outside the process that properly created them. When you send a `fd` to other process, you are just sending a bunch of bytes - nothing more, nothing less.

The only way you can move a *working* `fd` from one process to another is to `fork()` a process containing the `fd` to be passed.

If you want some process to connect to a particular Unix socket you should pass a unix socket file system entry name to that process. The receiving process can properly create a socket and make a connection afterwards.

I don't know why didn't you have problems with passing a tcp socket `fd`. Perhaps if you post the relevant parts of your code the reason will be revealed.

Comment: `fork()` is not the only way to move a working fd from one process to another. The `SCM_RIGHTS` [ancillary message](http://linux.die.net/man/3/cmsg) allows sending a file descriptor to another process over a unix socket.

Comment: I used the SCM_RIGHTS ancillary message to pass a tcp connection and when I try to pass a connection which is UDS one I fail. So, is there a reason to it or am I doing something wrong

Comment: @AC78 post a new question describing your problem

Comment: I managed to sort it out. UDS fd is just like anu other socket fd and it can passed through other UDS Connection

Comment: I don't understand...the answer say that is not possible, but is clear in the comment from Sam Miller that indeed it is possible...Then, AC78 you say that you sovled your problem, but you don't say how...